# JavaScript file not found by application

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, laravel-blade

I'm new to npm and Laravel in general. At this moment I am trying to assemble several new JS packages using npm. So I ran `npm install` / `npm run dev` and it managed to create new app.js file in public directory. But for some reason, when I attempt to reach it on browser it says

```
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://site/js/app.js
```

Link is generated in my views by Blade:

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

I thought it could be my local server fault, but when I am trying to directly access http://site/js/app.js it works fine... Can you tell me what's can be wrong with it?

Comment: That error is mentioning the source map, not the actual source itself. Does the source file also not work?

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, it seems to be not working